# android activity/service works only if phone connected to pc

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I know this sounds weird, but I created a simple timer with an `activity` and a `service` (started and bound).

In the activity I also implemented `onStart` and `onStop` just logging a message (Log.d(TAG,"activity started/stopped").

The fact is that if the phone is connected to the pc everything seems to work. I can start the timer, pause it, modify and restart it. Open other apps and it keeps working on the background. I can recall it and I see the actual countdown going down. If it finish I can recall the activity from a notification and stop the ringing. etc etc

If the phone it's detached from the pc, that it works like there is no service at all. So the activity runs and if I press the home button it goes on the background and keeps working for a couple of minutes than it stops.

I can see the process in the **running applications** and if I recall the activity it restart from the point where it paused. That is, I set 10 minutes, I click start and then the home button. After 2-3 minutes it stops working and if I recall the activity it continues counting down from 8-7 minutes...

Any idea?

The activity:

```
package com.sleone.cookingtimer;

import com.sleone.cookingtimer.TimerService.LocalBinder;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

import kankan.wheel.widget.WheelView;
import kankan.wheel.widget.adapters.NumericWheelAdapter;
import android.util.Log;

public class TimerMainActivity extends Activity {
    // private CookingTimer timer;
    // suppressWarnings because is initialized binding to the service

    private TimerService timerService;
    private Intent timerServiceIntent;
    private final String TAG = "TimerMainActivity";

    private WheelView hoursWheel ;
    private WheelView minutesWheel;
    private WheelView secondsWheel;

    /*
     * Initialize the activity
     */
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_timer_main);

        timerServiceIntent = new Intent(this, TimerService.class);
        startTimerService();

        // init the gui
        hoursWheel = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.hoursWheelView);
        minutesWheel = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.minutesWheelView);
        secondsWheel = (WheelView) findViewById(R.id.secondsWheelView);
        hoursWheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 6));
        minutesWheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 59));
        secondsWheel.setViewAdapter(new NumericWheelAdapter(this, 0, 59));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
        super.onStop();
        Log.d(TAG, "TimerMainActivity stopped");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();
        Log.d(TAG, "TimerMainActivity started");
    }

    private void startTimerService() {
        // connect to the service
        // leave the service in background
        Log.d(TAG, "Starting the TimerService");
        startService(timerServiceIntent);
        // interact with the service
        Log.d(TAG, "Binding to the TimerService");
        bindService(timerServiceIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private void stopTimerService() {
        unbindService(mConnection);
        stopService(timerServiceIntent);
    }

    /*
     * Disconnect from the service
     */
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Stopping TimerService");
        super.onStop();
        stopTimerService();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.timer_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public void controlTimer(View view) {
        Button controlButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.controlTimerButton);

        if (controlButton.getText().equals(
                getResources().getText(R.string.startTimer))) {
            if ((hoursWheel.getCurrentItem() == 0)
                    && (minutesWheel.getCurrentItem() == 0)
                    && (secondsWheel.getCurrentItem() == 0)) {
                return;
            }
            controlButton.setText(R.string.stopTimer);
            timerService.startTimer();
        } else {
            controlButton.setText(R.string.startTimer);
            timerService.stopTimer();
        }

    }

    /* Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService() */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get
            // LocalService instance
            LocalBinder binder = (LocalBinder) service;
            timerService = binder.getService();
            binder.createCookingTimer(TimerMainActivity.this);

            Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected() finished");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            Log.e(TAG, "TimerService unexpectedly disconnected!!");
        }
    };
}
```

The service:

```
package com.sleone.cookingtimer;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Binder;
import android.os.IBinder;

public class TimerService extends Service{
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    private CookingTimer timer;
    //private int timerServiceId;

    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public TimerService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods

            return TimerService.this;
        }

        // when the client connects to the service  instantiate the CookingImer
        public void createCookingTimer(TimerMainActivity timerMainActivity){
            timer = new CookingTimer(timerMainActivity);    
        }  
    }

    public void startTimer(){
        timer.startTimer();
    }

    public void stopTimer(){
        timer.stopTimer();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return mBinder;
    }
}
```

I don't think you need the timer itself. It;s just a `CountDownTimer` which `onTick` it updates the hours/minutes/seconds Wheel and `onFinish` plays a sound and create a `notification`.

Comment: When you say "connected to the PC", do you mean that you have a debugger running? What exactly do you mean by "connected to the PC"?

Comment: Post your code and stack trace...

Comment: Added the code.

@DavidWasser mmm do I have a debugger? I'm using eclipse. For sure I did not set up any debugger. Could eclipse have done something automatically?

Comment: Guys, as you see the service has a pointer to the activity in order to update the gui onTick().

could be that when the activity itself stops then the service cannot update the activity anymore and starts waiting?

and if so, why does it works on the emulator and/or int the phone connected with the cable to the pc?

Answer (score 0):

You might have some sort of race condition, that when connected to the PC, execution is a bit slower, but when not connected the timing is a bit different and the order of execution changes. It's hard to tell without the code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I guess I figured it out.

Basically I did not understand exactly that a service could also be paused when the cpu goes to sleep.

So, my guess is that while on the emulator or with the cable connected the cpu never goes to sleep because there is no battery consumption.

To wake up the application even from the cpu sleep I used an AlarmManger with the AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP flag.